# Optional forward slash regex URL path

Tags: regex

Hi guys looking for some assistance with my `regex`. I've managed to get this far:

`((^en-uk\/)|(^en-ca\/)|(^en-ie\/)|(^\/))about\/?$`

This will match the following URLS

- en-uk/about
- en-uk/about/
- en-ca/about
- en-ca/about/
- en-ie/about
- en-ie/about/

However what I'm trying to do is to also say that a forward slash at the start is optional so that these URLs would also match

- /en-uk/about
- /en-ie/about/

I understand that the `?` will make a character optional so for example tes?t would match test and tet so I tried updating the `regex` like this:

```
\/?((^ie\/)|(^en-ca\/)|(^uk\/)|(^\/))test\/?$
```

But it is also not working

Comment: just add `\/?` at the beginning so the `/´ is optional

Comment: I am curious why you have not tried adding `\/?` after `^` since you already have `\/?$` in your pattern.

Comment: I just didn't see it but now it makes sense by doing `(^\/?ie\/)` it would mean 1. Hast to start with ie/ but the / is optional

Comment: Why do you need so many capturing groups? I suggest to use only 1. Non-capturing groups are handy when you only need *grouping* alternatives without actually *stroring* the text they match. Please check my answer and let know if there is any concern.

Comment: Again this is probably down to lack of understanding on my part. I appreciate your feedback and will take it on board and look to improve my skills in this area.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use

```
^\/?(en-(?:uk|ca|ie))\/about\/?$
```

See the [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NAqCv6suxU6NpCx-)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\/?` - an optional `/`
- `(en-(?:uk|ca|ie))` - `en-` followed with 1 of the alternatives: `uk`, `ca` or `ie`
- `\/about` - `/about` string
- `\/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string